# Create an script that reads variables from the console and replace this values for the ones wrapped in curly brackets

Tags: bash, shell

I have a small assignment and this is the part that I am stuck on.
I have been given a text, and within the text there are strings like : {adjective},{noun} and so on. My script should allow the user to write whatever he/she wants in the console and I will replace those words in the text.

My approach so far is to make a for loop iterating through each line and somehow to use *sed* but I don't know how.
Any hint or help is highly appreciated.
Thank you in prior.

EDIT:
With my code so far I am able to replace the adjectives and I can't think of a way to use *if statements* to do the others.
Sorry for the lack of knowledge towards this site.

```
i=1
while [ $i -le 20 ]
do
   echo Please enter an adjective :
   read var
   sed -i "s/{adjective}/$var/g" file.txt
   i=$((i + 1))
done
cat file.txt
```

Here's an example file.txt file:

```
The {adjective} fox jumped over the lazy {animal}.
```

And here's a sample run:

```
Please enter a(n) adjective:  quick
Please enter a(n) animal:  dog
```

And here's the expected result.

```
$ cat file.txt
The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I just posted my code and my approach to it. Sorry about that mister.

Comment: What's `file.txt` look like? Is it ok for every replacement string of a type (such as `{adjective}`) in the file to be the same, or did you want to keep asking until they were all filled? MadLibs are a lot more fun with some variety...

Comment: HI Allorja, welcome to SO.  Before you start with the code, consider the expected behavior of your program.  Provide an example file.txt file ( it can be really simple ) and then take a stab at what the program execution would look like.  For instance, if file.txt contained: The {adjective} boy wrote "{exclamation}" on his paper.   Then may the program would ask for an adjective, then an exclamation like this "Please enter an adjective" and this "Please enter an exclamation"  .  You can then provide the code you tried to achieve these results.

Answer (score 0):

Best scripts are always non interactive. I have written your task as below :

#### Script

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $# -gt 6 ]] && echo "Too many arguments!! "

while [[ $# -ne 0 ]]
do
        [[ $1 == "--adj" ]] && { shift; adj=$1; shift; continue ; }
        [[ $1 == "--noun" ]] && { shift; noun=$1;  shift; continue ; }
        [[ $1 == "--file" ]] && { shift; file=$1;  shift; continue ; }
        echo "Unkwown option $1"  && exit 1
done


[[ -z "$file" ]] && { echo "You must specify a --file parameter" ; exit 2 ; }
[[ ! -z "$adj" ]] && sed -i "s/{adjective}/$adj/g" "$file"
[[ ! -z "$noun" ]] && sed -i "s/{noun}/$noun/g" "$file"
```

#### input.txt

```
You are a {adjective} {noun}
```

#### Usage

```
./populate.sh --noun 'mama' --adj 'big' --file input.txt
```

#### Resulting file

```
$ cat input.txt
You are a big mama
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that may  work for you:

```
file=$1

for variable in $( grep -o '{[^}]*}' $file )
do
  read -p "Please enter a(n) $variable: " var
  sed  -i.bk -e "s/$variable/$var/"     $file

done
```

Here's a sample invocation:

```
$ cat file.txt
The {adjective} fox jumped over the lazy {animal}.


$ ./madlibs.sh file.txt
Please enter a(n) {adjective}: quick
Please enter a(n) {animal}: dog


$ cat file.txt
The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```